# java, two integers, they are equal but

Tags: java

```
public void pop() {
    int a = stack.peek();
    int b = min.get(min.size()-1);
    System.out.println("a:"+a+" "+"b:"+b);
    if (a==b) {
        System.out.println("111");
    }
    if (stack.peek()==min.get(min.size()-1)) {
        System.out.println("222");
    }
    stack.pop();
}
```

I created a class called MinStack, here is the pop(), the variable stack is a Stack(Integer), and min is an ArrayList(Integer), but the second if stmt is not always working correctly.

I got console like this:

```
a:512 b:-1000
a:-1000 b:-1000
111
a:-1000 b:-1000
111
```

I think the "111" and "222" will always show together, but here is not.
If I change the second if stmt as `stack.peek()-min.get(min.size()-1)==0`, then it works correctly, why this happened?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I know where is wrong, I have to use stack.peek().intValue()==min.get(min.size()-1).intValue(), cause they are Integer.

Comment: ´Have you tried to debug your code?

Comment: both of them are Integer

Comment: can you add the content of min and stack as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue of Integer comparison. `stack.peek` and `min.get(min.size()-1)` both return `Integer`s. Even though they contain the same int value, they are not the same `Integer` instance, so the comparison returns false.

Change your code to :

```
if (stack.peek().equals(min.get(min.size()-1))) {
    System.out.println("222");
}
```

The alternative comparison `stack.peek()-min.get(min.size()-1)==0` returns true because here you are comparing two `int` primitives.